# Struggling to create a function from VLOOKUP with MIN baked into it

Tags: vba, excel

I've got a problem regarding Excel/VBA that I've tried to solve using VLOOKUP, however, it may in some cases not return the correct value. Let's say I have the following list in Excel

```
Country     Years
Germany      63
Germany      27
Germany      29
France       45
```

**and** in another worksheet I have a drop-down list containing France and Germany. I would like to find a function that can find the minimum years of the country I have selected. In the standard function `VLOOKUP` I would only get `63` for Germany, and attempting to bake in `MIN` also does not work. Is there any way I could create my own function (in `VBA`) that could do what I described?

Comment: There is but there are many formula that will do what you want.  is vba totally necessary?

Comment: It would be nicer

Comment: than theoretically without you providing the errant code and asking a specific question about the errors, this is too broad for this forum.  Unless all you want is: "Yes it is possible" as your one question implies you want.

Comment: @user9078057 Scott's a bit of a formula wizard, you'd be surprised

Comment: If you're interested, here's how to find min/max with vba https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/132404-max-min-vba.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Office 365 use:

```
=MINIFS(B:B,A:A,E2)
```

If you have 2010 or later then:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,B2:B5/(A2:A5=E2),1)
```

If it is prior to 2010 then use this array formula:

```
=MIN(IF(A2:A5=E2,B2:B5))
```

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when esiting edit mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Min with IF entered as array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
=MIN(IF(A2:A5=C2,B2:B5))
```

Data

[image: Data]

I have shown them on the same page but you can do across sheets e.g.

```
=MIN(IF(Sheet1!A2:A5=A1,Sheet1!B2:B5))
```